# Como fazer um método aguardar a resposta do servidor em java usando Retrofit2?

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Olá amigos tenho o seguinte método que faz requisição ao servidor:

```
public MetaDataR metodo1(final String m) {
            Call<MetaDataR> call2 = new RetrofitConfig().getMetasService().getMetas(m);
            call2.enqueue(new Callback<MetaDataR>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<MetaDataR> call, @NonNull Response<MetaDataR> response) {
                    if (response.body() != null) {
                        MetaDataR iten = response.body();      ////Quero retornar "iten" para o metodo1()                       

                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<MetaDataR> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                    // tratar algum erro
                    Log.e("Erro", "Erro ao buscar:" + t.getMessage());
                }
            });
            return null;
        }
```

Dessa forma ele retorna NULL sempre.  Preciso que ele me retorne o valor que vem do servidor, ou seja que ele aguarde a requisição e retorne "iten". É possível?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não<sup>(1)</sup>, não é possível.

As "chamadas" executadas pelo Retrofit têm o resultado retornado de forma assíncrona.

O resultado é obtido no método `onResponse()` ou, caso haja erro, no método `onFailure()`, da implementação da interface `Callback` passada ao método `enqueue()`.

<sub><sup>(1)</sup> Bem, [até é possível](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-synchronous-and-asynchronous-requests) se a *targetSdkVersion* for menor que 4.0. Em versões iguais ou superiores é lançada a excepção [NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/69894/2541).</sub>

Comment: Ok, obrigado @ramaral, vou digerir isso é tentar outra alternativa.